# Решение задачи sql oracle

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте, есть две таблицы firm и firm_pe.

```
CREATE TABLE firm
  (fNum NUMBER(4),
   fName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   fProductType VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   fBudget NUMBER(7,3) NOT NULL),
   CONSTRAINT firm_pk_snum PRIMARY KEY (fnum)
);

CREATE TABLE firm_pe
(  fpeNum NUMBER(4),
   fpeName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   fpeProductType VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   fpeBudget NUMBER(7,3) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fpe_pk PRIMARY KEY (fpeNum)
);
```

Поставил такую задачу себе, в таблице firm_pe найти компанию с наименьшим бюджетом и перенести ее в таблицу firm. При этом, нужно использовать только неявные курсоры. Но компания должна переноситься только в том случае, если в таблице firm отсутствуют поставщики периферийного оборудования(т.е. в столбце fProductType не будет содержаться Peripheral). Решил задачу вот таким способом:

```
DECLARE
fpe_num number(4);
fpe_name VARCHAR2(20);
fpe_type VARCHAR2(20);
fpe_budget NUMBER(7,3);
BEGIN
SELECT fpenum, fpename, fpeproducttype, fpebudget
INTO fpe_num, fpe_name, fpe_type, fpe_budget
FROM firm_pe
WHERE fpebudget = (SELECT min(fpebudget) FROM firm_pe);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fpe_num||'  '||fpe_name||'  '||fpe_type||'  '||fpe_budget);

UPDATE firm SET fnum = fpe_num WHERE fproducttype = 'Peripheral';
  IF(SQL%NOTFOUND) THEN
  INSERT INTO firm(fnum, fname, fproducttype , fbudget)
    VALUES(fpe_num, fpe_name, fpe_type, fpe_budget);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Добавлена ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' фирма ' || fpe_name);
  END IF;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Данные добавляются, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при повторном вызове должна генерироваться ошибка, а информация просто обновляется. Видимо не правильно составлена строка:

UPDATE firm SET fnum = fpe_num WHERE fproducttype = 'Peripheral';

Подскажите, как правильно переписать и где я ошибся

Comment: А в каком месте и почему по вашему должна генерироваться ошибка?

Comment: IF(SQL%NOTFOUND) THEN
это условие получается всегда true

Comment: Хотя в первом запросе может появляться ошибка "запрос вернул более одной строки", в случае если в БД окажется более одной записи с одинаковым fpebudget и он будет минимален

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что запросом `UPDATE firm SET fnum = fpe_num WHERE fproducttype = 'Peripheral';` вы меняете все записи в таблице firm у которых fproducttype равен Peripheral, причем пытаетесь изменить первичный ключ этой таблицы, что в общем то конечно разрешается, но в практике такое не встречается. Так что я не понял, чего вы пытаетесь достичь этим update (и да, ошибка на update то же может быть, если в таблице firm более чем у одной строки будет fproducttype = 'Peripheral')

Comment: Я так подозреваю вам надо было писать `select count(1) into CNT from firm where fproducttype = 'Peripheral'` и делать потом IF CNT=0 THEN

Answer (score 1):

1. Совершенно непонятно, зачем вам две идентичные таблицы, отличающиеся только именем. Пока это выглядит как ошибка проектирования. Слейте таблицы в одну и добавьте столбец, в котором будет храниться признак, по которому вы сейчас различаете фирмы.
2. Как уже сказали в комментариях, ваш первый запрос богат на потенциальные ошибки. Перепишите его так:

   ```
   select fpenum, fpename, fpeproducttype, fpe_budget
     into fpe_num, fpe_name, fpe_type, fpe_budget
     from (select fpenum, fpename, fpeproducttype, fpe_budget, 
                  row_number() over (order by fpebudget) rn
             from firm_pe)
    where rn = 1;
   ```
3. Требование "компания должна переноситься только в том случае, если в таблице firm отсутствуют поставщики периферийного оборудования" выглядит странно. Вам нужно, чтобы был ровно один поставщик на таблицу? В любом случае, ваш код эту задачу не решает.
4. Ошибка, которую вы ожидаете при повторном запуске - это ORA-00001 при вставке? Не дожтетесь, при втором запуске у вас `SQL%NOTFOUND` будет `false`, и вставки не будет.
5. Совершенно непонятное выражение `UPDATE`. Может, вы хотели сказать

   ```
   UPDATE firm SET fproducttype = 'Peripheral' WHERE fnum = fpe_num;
   ```

   В таком виде это намного более осмысленное выражение.
6. Извлечь строку из одной таблицы и вставить в другую можно намного проще - с помощью одного оператора `MERGE`. Например, так:

   ```
   merge firm f
   using (select fpenum, fpename, fpeproducttype, fpe_budget
            from (select fpenum, fpename, fpeproducttype, fpe_budget, 
                         row_number() over (order by fpebudget) rn
                    from firm_pe)
           where rn = 1) fpe
      on fpe.fnum = f.fnum
    when matched then update
     set fproducttype = 'Peripheral'
    when not matched then 
   insert (fnum, fname, fproducttype , fbudget)
   values (fpe.fpenum, fpe.fpenum, fpe.fpeproducttype, fpe.fpe_budget);
   ```